Roblox: Failed to load animation - sanitized ID: rbxassetid://187
I got this error:
 Failed to load animation - sanitized ID: rbxassetid://1713688057
Here is my roblox script:
    local animation = script.Animation
    local humanoid = script.Parent:WaitForChild("Humanoid")
    local track

    track = humanoid:LoadAnimation(animation)
    track.Priority = Enum.AnimationPriority.Core
    track.Looped = true
    track:Play()

I have an animation instance in the script. I used the animation id of the keyframe sequence since when I uploaded it to roblox and grabbed it from the toolbox it just gave me the keyframe sequence
I wanted to play an animation on a rig in the workspace from the server. Can someone help?

The sanitized ID error is caused by you not having ownership of said animation. Sorry!
If there is anything else you need to know I would be happy to help.

Thanks, I redid the animation and everything and it worked. Maybe I had a typo or something...
